# WeakSubscribe in MvvmCross doesn't work correct

Tags: c#, mvvmcross

**Context:**

I have an unknown Model-Object which contains one or more ObservableCollections.
These collections contains objects which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
I now want to observe the PropertyChangedEvents for all objects inside the Model-Object.

**What I have done:**

So I wrote this method which uses reflection to find the specific objects. This all works fine. Except the part where it comes to the MvvmCross function WeakSubscribe. I really like the idea behind, but it seems it loses the reference and don't fire the event.

Strange: If I debug this code it works correct, but without breakpoints it's not working.

```
    private void SubscribeToDetailData()
    {
        var tempTokenList = new List<MvxNotifyPropertyChangedEventSubscription>();

        var fieldInfos =
            DetailData.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().Where(f => Helpers.IsSubclassOfRawGeneric(typeof (ObservableCollection<>), f.PropertyType));

        foreach (var fieldInfo in fieldInfos)
        {
            var collection = fieldInfo.GetValue(DetailData) as IEnumerable<object>;
            if (collection == null) 
                continue;

            foreach (var inpc in collection.Cast<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
            {
                tempTokenList.Add(inpc.WeakSubscribe((sender, e) =>  DetailDataPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName))); 
            }
        }
        _subscriptionTokens = tempTokenList.ToArray();
    }

    // This method is never raised
    private void DetailDataPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        
        if (_enabledFields.Evaluate(DetailData, propertyName))
             RaisePropertyChanged(() => FieldEnabledState);
    }
```

Comment: It would help if you could add a bit more info (tags?) about which platforms and compilers you are seeing this on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that your subscribed `Action` is getting garbage collected.

This can be caused, I think, if the compiler creates an instance of an anonymous class to implement your anonymous `Action`. I wouldn't normally expect this to happen in your code because you are not using any local variables in your `Action` - but this could be the case.

Does your code work if you change the subscription to:

```
tempTokenList.Add(inpc.WeakSubscribe(DetailDataPropertyChanged));
```

with the method signature changed to:

```
private void DetailDataPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: This way it is working. But i want to use local variables in this action. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Yes - but you need to store a strong reference to the `Action` somewhere

Comment: Local variable was causing me subscription to be garbage collected too